# Why does a concentration inequality imply equivalence of moments and exponential integrability of the square?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, concentration-of-measure

I have the following basic question about a concentration inequality:

Let $X$ be a random variable, denote by $m$ a median and assume that for every $t>0$ one has

$$
P \left( \left| X - m \right| > t \right)
\leq
C e^{-t^2/\lambda}
$$

for some positive constants $C$ and $\lambda$.

Why does this imply that $\operatorname{E} \left( e^{a X^2} \right) < \infty$ for some $a>0$ and that all moments are equivalent, i.e. for all $0<p,q<\infty$ one has $\left\lVert X \right\rVert_p \leq K_{p,q} \left\lVert X \right\rVert_q$, where $\left\lVert X \right\rVert_p^p = \operatorname{E} \left( \left| X \right|^p \right)$ for positive constants $K_{p,q}$?

**Background:**
I have condensed the above statement from Theorem 4.7 on page 100 of the book *Probability on Banach spaces* by Ledoux and Talagrand. However, in case there are necessary assumptions I have stripped, here is the full statement for reference:

Let $X$ be a Rademacher series in a Banach space $B$ such that for some countable subset $D$ in the unit ball of $B^{\ast}$ it holds that $\left\lVert x \right\rVert = \sup_{f \in D} \left| f(x) \right|$. Denote by $M$ a median of $\left\lVert X \right\rVert$. Then

$$
P \left( \left| \left\lVert X \right\rVert - M \right| > t \right)
\leq
4 \exp \left( -t^2/8\sigma^2 \right),
$$

where $\sigma = \sup_{f \in D} \sqrt{\operatorname{E} \left( f^2(X) \right)}$.
In particular, there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $\operatorname{E} \left( \exp \left( \alpha \left\lVert X \right\rVert^{2} \right) \right) < \infty$ and all moments of $X$ are equivalent: that is, for any $0<p,q<\infty$, there is a constant $K_{p,q}$ depending on $p,q$ only such that $\left\lVert X \right\rVert_p \leq K_{p,q} \left\lVert X \right\rVert_q$.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer to provide, actually I'd be interested in the solution too. Maybe you'd have better luck asking over at [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @StratosFair I think if nobody can answer it here, than a better place would actually be mathoverflow, but in my opinion there should definitely be some people here who could give an answer. Maybe it's too simple and we're overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential tails follow by applying Markov inequality and the finiteness of $\mathbb E e^{aX^2}$. Such random variables are called subgaussian random variables. For more details, see [1, Proposition 2.5.2].

The equivalence of moments is a rather subtle issue. The subgaussian assumption would imply that $\|X\|_p = O(\sqrt{p})$ for all $p\geq 1$. However, the equivalence of moments does not hold in general without additional assumptions, and that is where it is crucial that $X$ is a Rademacher series. This equivalence of moments for Rademacher Series is also related to the famous Khinchine-Kahane inequality. See, for example, [Wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality), [A short proof by  Rafał Latała; Krzysztof Oleszkiewicz](https://eudml.org/doc/216056), [a recent talk by Tomasz Tkocz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2yMvmvNaFI).

[1] High-Dimensional Probability, Roman Vershynin. [https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood it now! Actually I was way too quick and should have read the proof in the cited book, where they explicitly prove the equivalence of moments. The theorem is stated in a somewhat confusing way, as they write "In particular", which suggests that everything which comes after this phrase is a simple consequence of the concentration inequality. Well, I guess the meaning of "simple" is a lot different to Ledoux and Talagrand than it is for me...

Comment: I'm glad I could help.